# Application Deployment - Web + REST backend

Tags: heroku, deployment, amazon-web-services

I have an application which ember.js based front end, express.js based REST APIs with postgre as DB. There is also an android application consuming the REST APIs.

I want to deploy this application in cloud. I am very new to this area and not sure what approach to take that will be economical too. Its a startup application and will not have huge traffic in the start. I have been doing RnD on heroku and amazon aws.

Can any one please guide what deployment setup will be reliable and economical for me? Should I use cloude Db?. Any guide line or reference material will be great help.

Sorry If you find this question too generic.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS EC2 micro instance initially which is low cost.
Once you create the instance, you can install the tools required for you in instance.

What you need is create a AWS account and create the instance. In order to create a instance you can do it from console. Later you can access the instance using secrete key and access key. If you are a new user to AWS. Yo can get the usage free for one year.

As part of AWS’s Free Usage Tier, new AWS customers can get started with Amazon EC2 for free.

More details about free usage and [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

As your application grows you can use Opscode Chef or puppet for configuration management.